# how to use phpmyadmin database in visual studio 2010?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, phpmyadmin, mdf

I have my database in phpmyadmin.

Now I have to use that database in SQL server database.

But I cannot import .SQL file into visual studio 2010.

So please give me a solution so that I can use that database and perform CRUD operation also.

Comment: Why are you using Visual Studio? What steps did you take? What results did you expect? In which step did you get a different result? What was the difference?

Comment: improved readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so im trying to help you dude. but first, you must understand that phpmyadmin is just an RDMS environment for accessing, configuring, managing, administering, and developing all components of the RDMS. So what does it mean? you can still work on visual studio probably c# or vb (i guess) so you can perform a CRUD operation. How? these are the things you need to do:

1. know how to connect your prepared .net language (c# or vb) - you might need to look at Connector/NET mysql. you can google, its free.
2. familiarized on the said library.
3. find some tutorial on how to do crud operation. maybe [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNet-46-CRUD-Using-MySQL-f21a1d87) article is great for you. Good Luck